# Confusion about Golang embeded interface field assignment in context package

Tags: go

When I read the `context` package source code, I found that there is an `Context` interface field in the `cancelCtx` struct. In the `newCancelCtx` method,it assigns the `parent` parameter to the `cancelCtx.Context`.
I am confused about that is such assignment a soft copy or a deep copy? 
Does the `Context` field in struct `cancelCtx` holds a pointer to the `parent` interface?

```golang
// Canceling this context releases resources associated with it, so code should
// call cancel as soon as the operations running in this Context complete.
func WithCancel(parent Context) (ctx Context, cancel CancelFunc) {
    c := newCancelCtx(parent)
    propagateCancel(parent, &c)
    return &c, func() { c.cancel(true, Canceled) }
}

// newCancelCtx returns an initialized cancelCtx.
func newCancelCtx(parent Context) cancelCtx {
    return cancelCtx{Context: parent}
}
```

Comment: There are no "deep copies" in Go, so no these are just copies. "Does the Context field in struct cancelCtx holds a pointer to the parent interface?" No, obviously not as there is no `*` used (and pointers to interfaces are used rarely if at all). I have no idea what your test code is trying to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

An interface contains a pointer to the underlying data item and the type. When you assign a value to an interface, you assign that two values: a pointer to the value (or a pointer to the copy of the value), and the type. So, it is not deep copy.

You test code prints `a` for the first case and `b.impl` for the second case, and I'm guessing that's why the output looks confusing. Print `b` for the second case and it should be obviuos.